# Windows7 & Samba (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) - error on change password

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, samba

I have a fully working setup of Samba4 (non-AD) on Ubuntu 14.04.01 with Win7 clients. When a user tries to change his (samba) password from the Win7 client, an error 1351 occurs. No error messages in the samba error logs show up. Suggestions how to adress this problem?

NOTE:

ERROR_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO 1351 (0x547): Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.